# How do I clean up my layers after outlining strokes and dividing?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, stroke, pathfinder

[image]Hey all. So I'm creating a design in Illustrator. I want all of the shapes to have an even outline, but no stoke. In order to accomplish this I add the stroke and outline the strokes. Afterwards I divide all of the shapes in order to delete any overlapping shapes to create a clean gap in between all of my shapes. Is there an easier way to do this? The end result looks good, but I have to delete a lot of extra shapes in order to keep the design 1-color.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going off the assumption that all of the strokes (That you want to delete) are the same color.

You will first want to expand all of the shapes `Object -> Expand`.

You will have to use the pathfinder options to separate the different shapes. Select all of the shapes and use the Divide option in the pathfinder window (Maybe someone knows a none destructive way to separate the stroke and fill).

Use the Direct Select Tool to select the white stroke.

Go to `Select -> Same -> Fill Color`, you may now delete all of the strokes.